# stable_partition and getting O(nlogn) swaps

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

In [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition), we see that `std::stable_partition` perform O(n) swaps, if we are allowed to use extra memory. This, I can see. Every time we find an element in the range where our predicate is false, we swap that into another buffer. In the end, we can just copy this additional buffer to the end of our successful portion. [I also assume, in this case, `stable_partition` can be implemented with only Forward iterators]

What I don't get is, link says `stable_partition` performs O(nlogn) swaps, at most, if we are not allowed to use additional memory. Here is my attempt.

```
#include <utility>

namespace cho {

    template <typename BidirIt, typename Pred>
    BidirIt stable_partition(BidirIt begin, BidirIt end, Pred p) {
        BidirIt next_p = begin;
        for(BidirIt it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
            if(it == begin && p(*it)) {
                next_p++;
                continue;
            }
            if(p(*it)) {
                std::swap(*next_p++, *it);

                // riplle back swapped element to keep stability
                BidirIt cur = it;
                do {
                    BidirIt prev = --cur; cur++;
                    std::swap(*cur--, *prev--);
                } while(cur != next_p);
            }
        }
        return next_p;
    }

    template <typename ForwardIt, typename Pred>
    ForwardIt partition(ForwardIt begin, ForwardIt end, Pred p) {
        ForwardIt next_p = begin;
        for(ForwardIt it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
            if(p(*it)) {
                std::swap(*next_p++, *it);
            }
        }
        return next_p;
    }
}
```

In this case, I ripple back after the swap. So, if the distance between two successive true cases is `k`, I will perform `k` swaps. I think the worst case occurs, for my algorithm, when the range is reverse partitioned. If there are `p` items where predicate is false and `n-p` items where predicate is true, I will get O((n - p) * p) swaps. I thought about this and I could not see how can I get worst case O(nlogn).

Implementations in LLVM, I checked but could not really get how O(nlogn) swaps are achieved.

PS: My implementation might be wrong. I tested it with couple of inputs but that's it.

Comment: [Comparison of sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms). There are plenty of algorithms that are stable and work in `O(n log n)`

Answer (score 5):

Think recursively.

If both left half and right half are stable-partitioned, as in

```
0...01...10...01...1
     b    m    e
```

the only remaining operation is to rotate the `b, e` range bringing `m` to where `b` were. It will take `O(n)` swaps. Now think recursively, and stable partition both halves. There will be `O(log n)` levels of recursion, totaling `O(n log n)` swaps. In broad strokes,

```
iter stable_partition(begin, end) {
    if (end - begin < 2)
        return;
    iter mid = begin + (end - begin) / 2;
    iter left_break = stable_partition(begin, mid);
    iter right_break = stable_partition(mid, end);
    return rotate(left_break, mid, right_break);
}
```

Of course, you have to think carefully what `rotate` should return.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know C++ so I won't be able to write it for you, but it seems quite trivial to do if you have a stable sort implementation available. Well, this implementation would also need to sort in-place since you have the requirement not to use any additional memory. Provided that there is such a sort implementation out there, just sort the elements according to the following order relationship:

```
R(x, y) =  0 if  p(x) ==  p(y)
R(x, y) = -1 if  p(x) && !p(y)
R(x, y) =  1 if !p(x) && p(y)
```

Out of interest, which sorting algorithms would be suitable for this? Turns out there doesn't seem to be too many of them that tick all the boxes, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms).

Comment: Thanks, it was clear that It must have something to do with stable sorting but couldn't come up with a relation like this. Also, I was getting circular, thinking that stable sort would require a stable partition in turn.

Comment: Seems like such a sort isn't that easy to find, but some of the algorithms listed there match all conditions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms

Comment: You don't need to "sort" to do a stable partition. You just need a temporary buffer. You make 1-pass through your elements, moving elements to buffer if predicate is false, overwriting elements if predicate is true. When you have finished, you write the temporary buffer back after the last element that returned true. Job done

Comment: Using no buffer is the requirement of the question... It has to be an in-place partitioning with no additional memory

Comment: DIci: No additional memory is not possible for any of the adaptive algorithms: stable_sort, stable_partition, inplace_merge. I have seem complicated algorithms try to manage this. At the very least, you need 1-element on the stack. All else is done by rotation.